# url rewriting based on language selected by user

Tags: django, url-rewriting

I have a requirement where in I have to write this url `www.example.com/something/something/` to `www.example.com/en/something/something/` only when user chooses English language.

This is for an existing site already done in django with urls for the normal part done. Now if user chooses english language, I must rewrite the urls.

I thought i could manually start changing all the urls in django templates like so

```
{% if request.session.language == 'en' %} 
    <a href="/en/something"..>
{% else %}
    <a href="/something"..>
{% endif %}
```

But I have been asked not to do it that way as the number of links is too much to do it this way.

Then I thought of trying a custom middleware, where I could access the request object in `process_request` and do a `return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_url)`

But it seems `process_request` processes all the requests one by one, including the images and other links. But what I want is the first request, the actual url that was requested.

So I tried the same in a constructor in the middleware hoping it would get called only once and that would be the first request. But the problem I face is that `__init__` accepts only `self` and `**args` and not a `request` object, so I cannot access the session variables there.

I thought about trying this in apache, but I need to do the url redirect only if user selects the English language, not always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you read [internationalization in django urls patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns) from the documentation, you'll realize its a simple process.

1. Update your `urls.py`:

   ```
   from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

   urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
       url(r'^something/$', 'something.view', name='something'),
       # other urls like you would normally have
   )
   ```
2. Make sure `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` is in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` section of your `settings.py`.

That's it. Now your patterns will update based on the language selected by the user.

Comment: Mr Burhan Khalid thank you very very much. I will try this out immediately and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: May I ask, what this can do "i18n_patterns" in the url? This is my first time to see that, just want to learn something new :)

Comment: Hi mr Burhan, I am using django 1.3 and it throws an import error if I do this from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

Comment: You need to upgrade to 1.4 as this is only available in 1.4

Comment: Thanks Mr Burhan, I guess its out of my hands, as I am a developer and I cant decide on the same. Thanks again, and if possible can you suggest anything regarding middleware

Comment: You should really upgrade the system, but if you can't use [`django-localeurl`](http://pythonhosted.org/django-localeurl/) which will do the same thing as the out-of-box functionality in 1.4